# Loading images to Ajaxswing web application

Tags: java, ajax, image, swing, web

I would like to convert my desktop app to web app using Ajaxswing and as instructions say, I did all the same: http://agileengine.com/products/ajaxswing/doc/setup.html

The thing is that web app starts, but it doesn't load images. I put images to ajax images folder, but server still shows exception:

> javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file! at
>   javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)

Here is my code:

```
try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/images/blackStone.png"));
                img = img.getScaledInstance(this.pixelSize, this.pixelSize, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
                icon = new ImageIcon(img);
                this.setOpaque(true);
                this.setContentAreaFilled(true);
                this.setIcon(icon);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Where `img is Image`,`icon is ImageIcon` and `this is JButton`.
What should be path to `blackStone.png`.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: 1) There is no such thing as 'Ajaxswing' though 'Ajax/Swing' would refer to an app. that combines both. 2) Are you having trouble loading the images in the web app (which is running server-side) or the Swing app. (running client-side)? The latter will need to load the image by URL, since a file could only ever refer to a location on the user's machine.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm having trouble loading the images on client-side. My app tries to load 2D array filled with JButtons and each button may has icon like shown above. So my Image (img) is loaded runtime I guess.

Comment: *"I'm having trouble loading the images on client-side."* That trouble will continue as long as you try to load them by `File`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson How do I do this then? Like `try {
    URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(),"resources/images/blackStone.png");
    img = ImageIO.read(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
}`

Comment: If the client side app. has access to a `getCodeBase()` method, then ..sure. More typically images for an app. would be embedded in the executable, and `getResouece(String)` would be better. But change `catch (IOException e) { }` to `catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: @AndrewThompson now server doesn't show any exceptions, but I still don't see any images [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895932/image-loading-fails-in-browser-ajaxswing)

Comment: *"now server.."* I don't deal with server-side problems.

Comment: Is the **client-side** problem fixed?

Comment: Not entirely click in [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895932/image-loading-fails-in-browser-ajaxswing) if you mind.

Comment: Yes, I'd already seen it, and it sure seems like the image is loading OK in the client-side app..